# Usage of なんでもよくない

Tags: negation

もう　流されたんでもなんでもよくない!? 降参だ降参だ

The character is pondering this. He says this after pondering love and deciding to confess back to the girl who confessed to him.

My reading of 流された is that the one about "being swept away/being influenced" so he's saying I believe "It doesn't matter if I'm being influenced or whatever, I give up"

However, why is なんでもよくない here used instead of なんでもいい?

Answer (score 1):

It's a rhetorical question. The character is basically saying なんでもいい as you understood. If you choose to translate なんでもいい as "It doesn't matter," the original sentence would be "Does it matter?"

もう adds the sentence of "(not) any more," by the way.